# div shows only vertical scrollbar

Tags: html, css, canvas

Why does the div only show a vertical scrollbar?

The canvas is in both dimensions bigger than the div:

```css
div {
  padding-top: 2px;
  height: 709px;
  width: 889px;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <canvas width="1405" style="" height="2023"></canvas>
</div>
```

Any clarification would be appreciated.

Comment: It is showing both. You need to scroll down. http://jsfiddle.net/ehLcv7v7/

Comment: Which browser and operating system?

Comment: It shows only vertical scrollbar in my case. Tested with FF and chrome.

Comment: have you tried using `overflow:auto` on the canvas rather than div?

Answer (score 0):

@NKL you were right. But It was not possible to scroll down. But when I reduce the height the scrollbar is getting visible :)

Comment: Solved by decreasing the height by 15px

Answer (score 0):

```css
div {
  padding-top: 2px;
  height: 709px;
  width: 889px;
  overflow: auto;
}
.canvas{
    width:1405px;
    height:2023px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <canvas class="canvas"></canvas>
</div>
```

Check this out.